how to Enable sharing on All Networks control panel in powershell
I can enable some parts of the network sharing with PowerShell, but unfortunately I don't know how to enable the All network
win10 and win11
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried the following:
"Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Network Discovery' -Enabled True -Profile Any",
"Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'File and Printer Sharing' -Enabled True -Profile Any",
"Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System' -Name 'EnableLUA' -Value 0",
"Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' -Name 'fDenyTSConnections' -Value 0",
"Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Remote Desktop' -Enabled True",
"Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Remote Assistance' -Enabled True",
"Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Windows Remote Management' -Enabled True"


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
